# Como mantener la posicion sticky en el header

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando una estructura web con css grid y lo que que estoy intentando hacer posicion fija a mi header con position fixed, pero hacer esto rompe la estructura creada con grid, asi que para mantener la estructura de grid utilice position:sticky, parece que funciona bien pero cuando hago scroll el header solo se mantiene por un breve tiempo despues vuelve a subir:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header'
    'main'
    'footer';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 4rem 1fr 3rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <header class="header"></header>
  <main class="main">
    <span
      >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus
      quisquam delectus, sint commodi consequuntur fugiat at cupiditate,
      dolorum explicabo quaerat ratione! Est dicta quae cum ipsa et error,
      vitae porro? Eveniet, quibusdam sit. Optio deserunt provident, sequi
      quaerat odit ut recusandae non assumenda. Praesentium voluptatibus
      cupiditate pariatur autem ea error voluptatem, id dolore, harum
      impedit labore, deserunt quis voluptatum dicta. Facere sunt ad
      inventore vel eaque temporibus mollitia exercitationem voluptas vitae
      minima eligendi aut, aperiam necessitatibus amet asperiores quisquam,
      ut dicta esse. Magnam error cupiditate suscipit. Laborum, pariatur
      alias? Alias. Deleniti deserunt minima officiis cupiditate fugit neque
      sunt sit ipsum mollitia! Iste eius ducimus, illo omnis dignissimos
      reiciendis accusantium expedita, quos facilis excepturi totam magni
      voluptatum tempore repudiandae vitae ea. Culpa officia dolore veniam
      numquam impedit, cum voluptatem quod iste perspiciatis hic vel maiores
      nesciunt, odio magnam sit illum aliquid facilis! Autem quaerat quis
      maiores natus eveniet sunt sapiente vel. Numquam praesentium
      distinctio iusto, sed totam fugit? Repellendus sint sapiente officiis
      molestias ea corrupti iure dolor repudiandae commodi neque, corporis
      eaque aut pariatur, laborum, nam qui quia expedita. Cum, assumenda.
      Tempora sint laborum culpa? Odio assumenda laudantium nostrum
      architecto? Ducimus sint laborum consectetur assumenda cum nihil
      exercitationem iure tenetur itaque, libero porro earum quaerat
      voluptatibus officia laboriosam quos maxime dolor! Esse laborum aut
      officiis delectus numquam quia placeat nisi, praesentium adipisci
      optio, tempore ducimus. Natus tempora recusandae atque odit dolor?
      Quasi, dicta accusantium maxime perferendis debitis officia incidunt
      non dolor! Praesentium nostrum omnis, fugit beatae autem esse tenetur
      expedita dolore. Ea, debitis enim. Corporis, rem aliquam corrupti
      asperiores natus molestiae nisi perferendis. Suscipit a enim
      consequatur impedit nostrum. Veniam, assumenda. Tempora illo ad vero
      nesciunt quisquam adipisci quibusdam maxime error natus veritatis.
      Dicta, similique minima commodi incidunt deserunt sapiente magnam
      aliquid fugit eaque. Laborum laudantium accusamus temporibus nisi,
      excepturi modi. Eum nobis id, aliquam, nihil nam cupiditate amet ut
      harum blanditiis fugiat quasi, ea consequuntur facilis atque debitis!
      Beatae facere fuga, cum molestias modi provident voluptatum
      praesentium eius voluptatem sed. Asperiores ullam ipsum saepe et omnis
      possimus mollitia amet facere tempora, iure quibusdam beatae
      voluptatem maxime nemo quos. Provident dolores quos eos impedit ea at
      id, eligendi iusto pariatur aspernatur. Eveniet, minima
      necessitatibus? Labore beatae ea laudantium temporibus odit, ipsa
      eaque consequuntur saepe pariatur sequi qui delectus sunt provident
      possimus facilis, iure, id molestias fugit cupiditate explicabo
      aspernatur odio distinctio? A eaque eveniet voluptatem explicabo
      minima fugit qui reiciendis omnis, repellendus fugiat tempore quae
      tenetur distinctio, ratione hic officia autem dicta? Ipsam quod
      placeat veritatis neque quisquam? Cupiditate, expedita eveniet.
      Accusamus reprehenderit esse exercitationem, obcaecati saepe nesciunt
      voluptate harum neque, ad inventore autem fugit consectetur! Iste at
      odit sequi facilis dolores. Delectus sint minima corporis qui animi
      incidunt? Magnam, deserunt. Sint molestias officia aliquid velit
      pariatur sapiente voluptatibus, incidunt, officiis, blanditiis eveniet
      odio eligendi magnam deserunt suscipit quo cum rerum ipsa eum fugiat
      ab. Aut maxime ut rem? At, eaque. Minus veritatis sunt earum dolor,
      officiis sapiente eius numquam nostrum laborum voluptates facilis aut
      unde, beatae, omnis enim magnam. Culpa dolor voluptate non aliquid
      fugiat sapiente molestias, laudantium et dolore? Nisi nulla
      voluptates, placeat eligendi error eveniet ex nobis libero modi veniam
      enim cupiditate quisquam facilis quod voluptas, quo quam! Consectetur
      velit dolorem labore, ea eius repellendus pariatur itaque fugit? Est
      necessitatibus perspiciatis fugit nemo autem sapiente? Repellat
      impedit, natus ipsam soluta suscipit expedita minima tempore,
      asperiores nulla tenetur mollitia quia sequi quidem omnis voluptatum
      possimus excepturi atque ad qui? Dignissimos tenetur at ut harum.
      Molestias, repellendus officia? Soluta sunt ullam esse vel pariatur
      tempora ab inventore ex nemo nostrum voluptatibus laboriosam
      doloremque saepe aperiam deserunt, iste sint molestias animi.</span
    >
  </main>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Entonces necesitas que el header siempre este visible sin importar el desplazamiento?

Comment: si es lo que necesito, pero he intentado con overflow tambien pero no me funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que se define está correcto. El elemento padre, .main-container, es de 100vh, lo cual, al desaparecer del área visible, termina el efecto stycky. (.header solo será sticky mientras esté visible .main-container).
La única solución es darle más height a .main-container o, crear el header fuera de este, y que sea su elemento padre el body.

Comment: muchas gracias no sabia que ese era el problema